# highchart dateformat return different date

Tags: highcharts

I've a problem using highchart. 
The dateformat return incorrect value.

For Example.

```
var min= 1535727600000;

// Date Object
console.log(new Date(min); 
// Sat Sep 01 2018 00:00:00

// moment.js
console.log(moment(new Date(min)).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
// 2018-09-01 00:00:00

// highchart.js
console.log(Chart.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', new Date(min));
// 2018-08-31 15:00:00
```

I use it in xAxis's min and max.

actually min is 2018-09-01 00:00:00.
But the dateformat in highchart return 2018-08-31 15:00:00.

What can I do..?

Comment: Hi! Please look at my answer at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528730/high-chart-displaying-wrong-month-value-in-xaxis/50531052#50531052)  You are dealing with a timezone offset, so you probably need to specify the timezone in your highcharts configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High chart Displaying wrong month value in xaxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528730/high-chart-displaying-wrong-month-value-in-xaxis)